# How to determine date of pilot license?

Tags: general-aviation

I wonder if someone can tell me how to find out what year my Dad got his private pilot license as well as his commercial pilot license? BC Canada
Thank you.

Comment: Canadian pilots have a 6 digit file number which is sequential. It also corresponds to the pilot licence number in most cases. It may help narrow down the year it was issued. Do you know his pilot licence number or file number?

Comment: Mine's from 1975, and the 1st 3 digits are 159.

Comment: @John K That fits because mine is from 1976 and my licence and file number is 160xxx.

Comment: Bah!  1976.  Just a youngster. lol   When did you start with Air Casual?

Comment: Not until 2000. I flew bush from 1979-1989, then Canadian Regional 1989-2000.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the number.  I am hoping we find his license somewhere in his things.  I was hoping also that there is a data base where one could look up his name and find out.